# entity manager implicit transaction commit

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, persistence, entitymanager

Let's take into consideration the following code snippet:

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="EmployeeService")

    EntityManager em;

     public void assignEmployeeToProject(int empId, int projectId)
     {
        Project project = em.find(Project.class, projectId);
        Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, empId);
        project.getEmployees().add(employee);
        employee.getProjects().add(project);
     }
}
```

please note that this example refers to Transaction Scoped,container managed Entity Manager.

from [javacodegeeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/jpa-2-entitymanagers-transactions-and-everything-around-it.html):

> By the end of 2nd line in the method both project and employee
>   instance are managed. At the end of the method call, the transaction
>   is committed and the managed instances of person and employee get
>   persisted. Another thing to keep in mind is that when the transaction
>   is over, the Persistence Context goes away.

I really cannot understand how does the entity manager knows the method is closed and implicitly commits the transaction...
Am I missing something here ?
Should we commit the transaction explicitly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing something:

Your service isn't just an instance of `EmployeeServiceImpl` but of a proxy class which wraps `EmployeeServiceImpl` and every public method in it. And when your method exits the wrapping method takes over and commits the transaction. If you debug your application and set  a breakpoint in `assignEmployeeToProject()` you can see very easily what is happening in the stacktrace.

Comment: Interesting...and the container makes this happen automatically to any class it needs to inject an EntityManager to?

Comment: Exact - if you've got no `@PersistenceContext`, you won't have any transaction wrapping - although you will have (in most cases) other proxy classes that wrap your service - depending on the container.